# How to call a form from a gridview button click?

Tags: asp.net

I am using a Gridview in my application which contains button field as below.

```
<asp:GridView ID="grvAccrualData" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" ForeColor="Black" Font-Names="Arial"

                        BackColor="#B10633" __designer:wfdid="w9" AllowPaging="True" Width="100%" OnRowCommand="grvAccrualData_RowCommand">
                        <PagerSettings FirstPageText="&amp;lt;&amp;lt; First" LastPageText="Last &amp;gt;&amp;gt;"
                            Mode="NextPreviousFirstLast" NextPageText="Next &amp;gt;" PreviousPageText="Prev &amp;lt;">
                        </PagerSettings>
                        <FooterStyle BackColor="#B10633" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White"></FooterStyle>
                        <RowStyle Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt" HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle" BackColor="Ivory" />
                        <Columns>
                            <asp:BoundField DataField="AccrlHeaderAccrualNo" HeaderText="Accrual Number">
                                <ItemStyle HorizontalAlign="Left" VerticalAlign="Middle"></ItemStyle>
                            </asp:BoundField>
                            <asp:ButtonField ButtonType="button" CommandName="AccrualDetail" HeaderText="Debit Generation" Text="Account" />
                        </Columns>
                        <PagerStyle HorizontalAlign="Center" BackColor="#B10633" ForeColor="Black"></PagerStyle>
                        <HeaderStyle BackColor="#B10633" Font-Names="Arial" Font-Size="8pt" ForeColor="White">
                        </HeaderStyle>
                        <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#FFC0C0"></AlternatingRowStyle>
                    </asp:GridView>
```

And my server side code is :

```
protected void grvAccrualData_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.CommandName == "AccrualDetail")
    {

    }
}
```

In this server code I want to call a form or a webpage on button click.

Answer (score 0):

Use

```
Response.Redirect("~/WebPage.aspx");
```

Or if you want to pass parameter along with this means then use QueryString.